# How to instruct Mindstorms EV3 from PC conditionally?

Tags: ev3, remote-control, ev3dev, python

I want to direct my LEGO Mindstorms EV3 creature from my PC conditionally (ev3dev, Python). The idea is that the program runs on the computer, collects real-time data from different sources, processes them, and instructs the robot via Wifi/Bluetooth step by step. (The data collection and procession is quite computational so the main program cannot be run on the Brick.) The process is basically remote-control but by the PC program directly.

Is it feasible? So far I know only the way when one should upload the full program to the Brick, but this way there is no option to interact with the Brick continuously.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running ev3dev on the EV3, you can use RPyC to remotely execute Python code on the EV3.

Resources:

- [Python-ev3dev. Working with ev3dev remotely using RPyC](https://ev3dev-lang.readthedocs.io/projects/python-ev3dev/en/stable/rpyc.html)
- [EV3 PYthon. RPyC](https://sites.google.com/site/ev3python/learn_ev3_python/rpyc)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible and feasible to communicate from a program on your PC through bluetooth with an EV3 brick, several example projects can be found on the internet.

Assuming you want to code Python on your PC, I found this link: http://ev3directcommands.blogspot.com/2016/01/no-title-specified-page-table-border_94.html